# Is there a good program to run against the magento EE DB to analyze corruptions?

Tags: database, core, resources, ee-1.14.2.4

If core resource and other tables are corrupted.

Common errors would be certain core functions trying to re-instantiate tables or views. I notice i get lots of errors for weird install files from time to time.

Just curious if there is something out there or the best thing available is the database repair tool?

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html

Additionally, does the DB repair tool generate a report after it fixes and repairs your DB?

Basically, I'm just looking for a tool that will run against my DB and generate a health report.

Cheers!